# Scala append elements to Indexed Sequence

Tags: list, scala, sequence, immutability

I have a indexed sequence of 10 doubles and I want to append few more doubles to the original indexed sequence. I tried using :: and ++ but it doesn't work. I can only use val.

```
val features = functionCount.map(_.toDouble).toIndexedSeq //original indexed sequence
features +=  avgLength //tried :: also
```

How do I append more doubles to this sequence, I need a IndexedSeq in the end.

Answer (score 4):

You *can't* change `features`, unless it's mutable. Given the comment that "you can only use val", this sounds like homework, and, if it is, I doubt you can use mutable sequences either. In that case, you have to abandon that approach and tackle the problem at a much higher level, with either recursion or folding.